# Error in printing optimal cutoff value / Type Error: unsupported operand type

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I have three lists:

```
FPR=[1.0,0.6437673130193906,0.22105263157894736,0.03102493074792244,0.00221606648199446,0.0]
TPR=[1.0,0.9407831900668577,0.7172874880611271,0.3638968481375358,0.10315186246418338,0.0]
thresholds=array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])
```

I am trying to retrieve optimal cutoff value. I have tried below code.

```
i = np.arange(len(TPR))
roc = pd.DataFrame({'tf' : pd.Series(FPR-(1-FPR), index=i), 'threshold' : pd.Series(thresholds,index=i)})
roc_th = roc.iloc[(roc.tf-0).abs().argsort()[:1]]
```

but I am getting below error in line 2

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Pls let me know if I can provide you with any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the first two lines to

```
FPR=np.array([1.0,0.6437673130193906,0.22105263157894736,0.03102493074792244,0.00221606648199446,0.0])
TPR=np.array([1.0,0.9407831900668577,0.7172874880611271,0.3638968481375358,0.10315186246418338,0.0])
```

When you are doing `1-FPR` at the line where you are defining the dataframe, you are trying to subtract 1 from a normal python list. This is not supported and hence your error saying that it can't subtract - from an int and a list. Scalar-Vector subtraction is only defined for numpy arrays.